# Are Family-wise Error and experiment-wise error completely interchangeable terms?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, terminology

Some times I can find in the very same source both terms, but without any explanation.
On the other hand, some paper only use one and some only use the another.
Are these different measures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they should not be regarded as identical; I think the *family-wise error* rate refers to the overall type I error rate for some specified collection of hypothesis tests, which might potentially be a subset of the tests in an experiment, or even the overall error rate across several experiments (for some reason), or not relate to an experiment at all, while the *experiment-wise error* rate could only reasonably refer to testing in an experiment and only to the family-wise error rate for that entire experiment.

Which is to say, to my mind the concept of experiment-wise error is a specific example (and perhaps the most common one) of family-wise error.

[What I find interesting is nobody seems to much concern themselves about the type II error rate on a family-wise basis -- at least not that I recall.]

Comment: It does a loot of sense and I agree with you, but it still hard to understant or even find examples of family-wise error that do not blend to the experiment-wise concept. Can you kindly provide some examples?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking -- are you saying you'd like an example of familywise error that's not experiment-wise? Pick any study that calculates a familywise error but which is not an experiment and you have an example.

Comment: Glen_b, Actually there is quite a bit out there on familywise type II error rates. See, eg, Chapter 18 of Westfall,P., Tobias, R. and Wolfinger, R. (2011). Multiple Comparisons and Multiple Tests Using SAS (2nd Ed.), SAS® Press, Cary, NC, which contains a nice summary.